Where does Drools Workbench store project DRL files
Before I start, I searched everywhere and I couldn't find an answer to my question.
I'm running Drools Workbench in docker container based on the image jboss/drools-workbench. I initiated a project with some DRL files inside.
How can I get the source files ?
I found that it uses an internal git repository located in wildfly/bin/.niogit
But it does not contain the plain files...

In general (not specific to workbench), a running service has the rules in-memory. But if you're fetching rules from somewhere they might be in a kjar.
